# codeigniter session work in setting controller,but not work in other files

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

As my title 
in my ***controller*** auth.php

```
...
$this->session->set_userdata('administrator.role', 'admin');
var_dump($this->session->userdata('administrator.role'));
//echo string(5)admin

redirect(base_url()."admin/");
...
```

Session work perfectly.
But when I need session in ***helper*** auth_helper.php

```
...
$obj=&get_instance();   
var_dump($obj->session->userdata('administrator.role'));
//echo booln(false)
...
```

this is my config.php

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 345600;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 600;
```

I have been checked for days and many resources
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Does the helper loaded from controller?

Comment: Yes helper is loaded

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->CI = &get_instance();   
var_dump($this->CI->session->userdata('administrator.role'));
```